# Why can I correctly plot a pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which I want to plot

```
obs=pd.read_csv(obsfiles[0], skiprows=1)
obs.columns = ['date', 'time', 'gw', 'temp', 'volts', 'pulses']
obs['date'] = pd.to_datetime(obs['date'])
obs=obs[(obs['date'] >= '2016-01-01')]
obs = obs.set_index('date')
obs['gw'].plot()
```

[image]

**Why is the data being plotted from 05 May? I don't have data before 07. I am not sure what is going wrong...**

```
In [7]: obs
Out[7]:
                 time      gw   temp  volts  pulses
date
2016-07-09   05:32:23  262.41  20.87  17.52       0
2016-07-09   17:32:23  241.59  20.90  17.84       0
2016-08-09   05:32:23  254.45  20.84  17.33       0
2016-08-09   17:32:23  230.87  20.90  17.68       0
2016-09-09   05:32:23  251.39  20.80  17.22       0
2016-09-09   17:32:23  224.44  20.90  17.62       0
2016-10-09   05:32:23  252.92  20.77  17.12       0
2016-10-09   17:32:23  242.81  20.84  17.27       0
2016-11-09   05:32:23  254.76  20.77  16.92       0
2016-11-09   17:32:23  228.42  20.87  17.42       0
2016-12-09   05:32:23  252.61  20.77  16.97       0
2016-12-09   17:32:23  233.63  20.84  17.29       0
2016-09-13   05:32:23  256.29  20.77  16.83       0
2016-09-13   17:32:23  235.16  20.84  17.21       0
2016-09-14   05:32:23  257.82  20.74  16.78       0
2016-09-14   17:32:23  240.67  20.80  17.08       0
2016-09-15   05:32:23  260.57  20.70  16.65       0
2016-09-15   17:32:23  236.38  20.80  17.10       0
2016-09-16   05:32:23  259.66  20.70  16.64       0
2016-09-16   17:32:23  234.55  20.80  17.07       0
```

## From comments

Thanks!

```
In [16]: obs=pd.read_csv(obsfiles[0], skiprows=1)
    ...: obs.columns = ['date', 'time', 'gw', 'temp', 'volts', 'pulses']
    ...: #obs['date']=parse_date_time(obs['date'])
    ...: obs['date'] = pd.to_datetime(obs['date'])
    ...: obs=obs[(obs['date'] >= '2016-01-01')]
    ...: obs = obs.set_index('date')
    ...: obs.sort_index()
Out[16]:
                 time      gw   temp  volts  pulses
date
2016-01-10   05:32:23  265.78  20.60  15.93       0
2016-01-10   17:32:23  238.53  20.67  16.28       0
2016-01-11   05:32:23  257.21  19.90  11.45       0
2016-01-11   17:32:23  234.55  20.13  12.91       0
2016-01-12   17:32:23  226.89  19.20   6.72       0
2016-01-12   05:32:23  237.00  18.93   0.15       0
2016-02-10   05:32:23  263.33  20.60  15.90       0
2016-02-10   17:32:23  241.59  20.67  16.21       0
2016-02-11   05:32:23  259.04  19.87  11.23       0
2016-02-11   17:32:23  235.16  20.10  12.78       0
2016-02-12   05:32:23  251.08  16.82   0.37       0
2016-02-12   17:32:23  229.04  19.06   6.05       0
```

Comment: I'm not sure but why did you have to do `obs=obs[(obs['date'] >= '2016-01-01')]` if you don't have data before 2016-07?

Comment: The data aren't sorted in the sample you show (and that's only a sample) so you can't really rule out "data before this date" just by looking at some of it. You cut off data before 2016, but the mask will still keep data in the first 5 months of 2016.

Comment: @QuangHoang For some reasons, I had a few hanging points in 1998, which I didn't need. So I removed them..

Comment: @ALollz How would I sort them correctly?

Comment: `obs = obs.sort_index()` (after the set index line)

Comment: @ALollz You're right! Thanks a lot!